# How to number unique words on each individual line, not miss paragraph?

Tags: python, bash, perl

Before anything I am reading English language and programming, but I am beginner now. So I did a lot of methods to learn EN ( self-study ) but finally I make a personal method to learn.
So I collected a lot of **short story** then, read those, day after day. Now I am doing this method as usual.
A week a go I started to learn **perl one-liner** and it was so useful to me.

However, I get into `perl -pe '$q=0; s/(\w+)/++Sq." ".$1'`
for content:

> just another
>   perl hacker
>   hacking perl code

it become to:

> 1.just 2.another
>   1.perl 2.hacker
>   1.hacking 2.perl 3.code

Okay, after I saw this **perl one-liner** I got an idea

For example I read this short-story:

> 1. Morning
>      He wakes up. He sees the sun rise. He brushes his teeth. His teeth are white. He puts on his clothes. His shirt is blue. His
>      shoes are yellow. His pants are brown. He goes downstairs. He gets a
>      bowl. He pours milk and cereal. He eats. He gets the newspaper. He
>      reads.
> 2. First
>      Day of School He goes to class. There is an empty seat in front. He sits in the seat. He looks around. There are different
>      people. He says "hi" to the girl next to him. She smiles. The teacher
>      comes in. She closes the door. Everyone is silent. The first day of
>      school begins.
> 3. Water on the Floor
>      She is thirsty. She gets a glass of water. She begins to walk. She drops the glass. There is water on the floor. The
>      puddle is big. She gets a mop. She wipes the water off. The floor is
>      clean. She gets another glass of water. She drinks it. She is happy.
> 4. Babysitting
>      Casey wants a new car. She needs money. She decides to babysit. She takes care of the child. She feeds him lunch. She reads
>      him a story. The story is funny. The child laughs. Casey likes him.
>      The child's mom comes home. The child kisses Casey. Casey leaves. She
>      will babysit him again.
>
> 5.a docter
>   Sam is a doctor. He takes care of people. He smiles at them. He gives them medicine. He gives stickers to the younger
>   patients. The younger patients like him. They see him when they are
>   sick. He makes them feel better. This makes him happy. He loves his
>   job. He goes home proud.

As you can see, it is very easy. But at the beginning, it is not easy for someone who just started to learn English.

So my idea is this. I want a script may be in **bash** or **perl** that I think **perl** is better, that script can read a lot of **short-story** that I have and for each unique work, it number the word in the place.

For example in the above context that I put, I want something like this:

> 1.He 2.wakes 3.up. He 4.sees 5.the 6.sun 7.rise. He 8.brushes 9.his 10.teeth 11.are 12.white He 13.puts 14.on his 15.clothes. ... so on.

Here the first **He** is unique so number it to 1.
And until the end of content the "He" word is ignored, and so on.
Then the script does this to second words, if it is unique, then numbers it, otherwise ignore it.

Also the paragraph and each line **must not miss**, because I print it out in paper and read daily.

For completing this idea to use by everyone else I need to have a **database** from one word that script is parsed so that I can after, for example 100 short-story, I see whet word I have read.
And use this **database** for ignoring the repeated word in the new short-story that I want to read.

Why am I doing this? Because this help me to know what word I have read and what word I have not read. Also It can be a good method for the others, so that they can learn English easily. please help me to develop this idea If you see something bad in my idea or if you know the similar idea like this, that have done,please tell me.

**In summary, I want a content that each word only once (one time) has been numbered**

Sorry guys, but I want to print the content without missing the paragraph. Please the photo

[image: my homework]

As you can see, I have to cross the new word in the **new short story** for read those in the future. The script must print paragraph with numbering word as usual so that I can save it, then I print it for reading on the paper.

I want to do in this form:
`$ script my_context.txt > new_context.txt`

Then I can print it out.

I am so sorry if you see some mistake in my writing. If you does not understand my idea please comment, so that I put explain it in more detail.

Thank a lot!

Comment: What kind of script do you have so far? You have only given us your question, no code.

Comment: @not_a_robot it does not matter, I know this three but a little, I want it work, may be perl is better to parsing the txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS=" +" -v ORS=" " '{key=$0;gsub(/[^A-Za-z]/,"",key); 
                              if(key in a)print $0;
                              else{a[key];print ++c"."$0}}' file
```

> 1.He 2.wakes 3.up. He 4.sees 5.the 6.sun 7.rise. He 8.brushes 9.his 10.teeth 11.are 12.white He 13.puts 14.on his 15.clothes. 16.His 17.shirt 18.is 19.blue. His 20.shoes are 21.yellow. His 22.pants are 23.brown. He 24.goes 25.downstairs. He 26.gets 27.a 28.bowl. He 29.pours 30.some 31.milk 32.and 33.cereal. He 34.eats. He gets the 35.newspaper. He 36.reads.

you can also make is non case-sensitive by changing the key as I did for filtering non alphabetical chars.

Comment: Thanks it work, but put extra newline at the beginning of the first line. First print 1. then newline then the other content.

Comment: I used you input file and produced this.  Did you test with another input file?

Comment: Well done, it work, but for having a database in the future what can I do? Because I have more than 1000 short-story that I want to read. I need a database of the old word that I have read to skip in the new content.

Comment: 1000 files are within the reach of this script.  If you want to do this incrementally, perhaps it makes sense to have a persistent data for the numbering.  However, it can be a simple text file storing `word -> index` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @words = <DATA> =~ /(\w+)/g;
my %seen;
my $count = 1;
foreach my $value (@words) {
  if ( !$seen{$value} ) {
    print "$count.$value ";
    $seen{$value} = 1;
  }
  else{
    print "$value";
  }
  $count++;
}
__DATA__
He wakes up. He sees the sun rise. He brushes his teeth are white He puts on his clothes. His shirt is blue. His shoes are yellow. His pants are brown. He goes downstairs. He gets a bowl. He pours some milk and cereal. He eats. He gets the newspaper. He reads.
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/bk1RBJ)**

Comment: Thanks but it ruins the paragraph, so I can not print it out

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat script.txt 
BEGIN {RS=" "; ORS=" "}       # the record is a word
{
    key=$0                    # separate key to clean it up
    gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"",key)  # remove ".," etc.
    key=tolower(key)          # and capitals
    if(!(key in a)) {         # if not seen before
        print ++i; a[key]     # print the running number
    }
} 1                           # and the word
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk short_story_in_2_paragraphs.txt
```

> 1 He 2 wakes 3 up. He 4 sees 5 the 6 sun 7 rise. He 8 brushes 9 his 10 teeth 11 are 12 white He 13 puts 14 on his 15 clothes. His 16 shirt 17 is 18 blue. His 19 shoes are 20 yellow. His 21 pants are 22 brown. He 23 goes 24 downstairs. He 25 gets 26 a 27 bowl. He 28 pours 29 some 30 milk 31 and 32 cereal. He 33 eats. He gets the 34 newspaper. He 35 reads.
>
> He wakes up. He sees the sun rise. He brushes his teeth are white He puts on his clothes. His shirt is blue. His shoes are yellow. His pants are brown. He goes downstairs. He gets a bowl. He pours some milk and cereal. He eats. He gets the newspaper. He 36 reads.

I don't understand the last number `36 reads`, thou :D.

Version 2(.1 :)

```
BEGIN {RS=" "; ORS=" "}              # the record is a word
NR==FNR {a[$0]; next}                # read the database of words into memory
{
    key=$0                           # separate key to clean it up
    gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"",key)         # remove ".," etc.
    key=tolower(key)                 # and capitals
    if(!(key in a)) {                # if not seen before
        print ++i; a[key]            # print the running number
        print key >> "database.txt"  # append word to database
    }
} 1                                  # and the word
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f script2.awk database.txt story.txt
```

It expect that `database.txt` exists and has at least one word in it:

```
$ echo -n a\  > database.txt
```

Comment: I've tested it on 2 different boxes with 2 different versions of Gnu awk, a mawk and an original-awk and it works with all of them. You are using the latest version of my script, right?

Comment: I am beginner but not such. I did your code step-by-step. I do not know, may by my `Ubuntu` or `awk` or something else has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and very dirty solution in Python...

```
story = 'He wakes up. He sees the sun rise. He brushes his teeth are white He puts on his clothes. His shirt is blue. His shoes are yellow. His pants are brown. He goes downstairs. He gets a bowl. He pours some milk and cereal. He eats. He gets the newspaper. He reads.'

already_seen = set()
count = 0
my_story_string = ''
for word in story.split():
    if word not in already_seen:
        count += 1
        res = " ".join([str(count), word])
        print(word_number_tuple)
        already_seen.add(word)
    else:
        res = word
        print(word)
    my_story_string += ' ' + res

>>> my_story_string
' 1 He 2 wakes 3 up. He 4 sees 5 the 6 sun 7 rise. He 8 brushes 9 his 10 teeth 11 are 12 white He 13 puts 14 on his 15 clothes. 16 His 17 shirt 18 is 19 blue. His 20 shoes are 21 yellow. His 22 pants are 23 brown. He 24 goes 25 downstairs. He 26 gets 27 a 28 bowl. He 29 pours 30 some 31 milk 32 and 33 cereal. He 34 eats. He gets the 35 newspaper. He 36 reads.'
```